# DeployStageOnce Script for Vuforia Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I am working on a Ground Plane project in Unity Vuforia. In the latest version of Vuforia there is a pre-defined check box instead of importing separate DeployStageOnce script. 
I want the seperate DeployStageOnce script. I want research it and know how it works. I cant find the script anywhere. Does anyone have it? Or a link? 
Please provide it if you have.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using Vuforia;
public class DeployStageOnce : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject AnchorStage;
    private PositionalDeviceTracker _deviceTracker;
    private GameObject _previousAnchor;

    public void Start ()
    {
        if (AnchorStage == null)
        {
            Debug.Log("AnchorStage must be specified");
            return;
        }
        AnchorStage.SetActive(false);
    }
    public void Awake()
    {
        VuforiaARController.Instance.RegisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
    }
    public void OnDestroy()
    {
        VuforiaARController.Instance.UnregisterVuforiaStartedCallback(OnVuforiaStarted);
    }
    private void OnVuforiaStarted()
    {
        _deviceTracker = TrackerManager.Instance.GetTracker<PositionalDeviceTracker>();
    }
    public void OnInteractiveHitTest(HitTestResult result)
    {
        if (result == null || AnchorStage == null)
        {
            Debug.LogWarning("Hit test is invalid or AnchorStage not set");
            return;
        }
        var anchor = _deviceTracker.CreatePlaneAnchor(Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), result);
        if (anchor != null)
        {
            AnchorStage.transform.parent = anchor.transform;
            AnchorStage.transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
            AnchorStage.transform.localRotation = Quaternion.identity;
            AnchorStage.SetActive(true);
        }
        if (_previousAnchor != null)
        {
            Destroy(_previousAnchor);
        }
        _previousAnchor = anchor;
    }
}
```

Comment: How did you extract the code? Is there a way I can extract and study other codes in vuforia Unity?